# Prepend or Append INSIDE <input> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am working off of a custom CMS with a custom Form Builder. There is no option to use a custom Placeholder for the input field.

I have an input tag as such:

```
<input type="text" style="width:390px;" id="Optiona200368a" maxlength="120" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$Optiona200368a">
```

I need the input tag to read

```
<input placholder="Email Address" type="text" style="width:390px;" id="Optiona200368a" maxlength="120" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$Optiona200368a">
```

Is there any way I can achieve this with JQuery?
Thank you!

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: So give it a `placeholder` attribute. What's the problem? You certainly won't do it with `.append`. That makes no sense.

Comment: I strongly recommend you spend an hour or two reading [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It really only takes that long, and it pays for itself extremely quickly.

Comment: Thanks T.J. ...it's funny because I was just going to admit and ask you that I really am a well rounded designer and very understanding of basic JQuery...I just don't know how to write it myself, so I was going to ask where I can find the basics to be able to write things like this myself. So thank you again, really appreciate it!

Comment: Like I 100% completely understand what you wrote...I am just not very understanding of like how to even start writing a basic script, what goes where, and most of the time what does what. Hah. Will read up! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to add a `placeholder` attribute. Yes, you can do that with jQuery:

```
$("#Optiona200368a").attr("placeholder", "Email Address");
```

If the `id` isn't reliable, you can use any other CSS selector within the `$()` bit to find the element.

It's important that the code adding the attribute runs *after* the element already exists. The best way to ensure that is to put the `script` tag containing it at the bottom of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. If you don't control where the script goes, though (and with some CMSs you don't), you can wrap the code in a jQuery "ready" handler like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Optiona200368a").attr("placeholder", "Email Address");
});
```

That defers the code inside the function until the main HTML parsing and loading is done, even if the script is above the body.

Comment: @Jason: Don't forget there's a 15-minute guard time in which OPs *can't* accept any answers. :-) So when things are really fast, they have to come back later and do it. (But thanks.)